# Rgd: HTaccess rewrite rules passing GET

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^myfile/(.+)?$ chapter.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^myfile/(.+)/(.+)?$ read.php?id=$1&num=$2 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

I tried the following

```
http://www.example.com/myfile/hellopanda
```

and also

```
http://www.example.com/myfile/hellopanda/123
```

In the folder of myfile, there are 2 files, read.php & chapter.php that do the following

```
print_r($_GET);
```

However when I tried the 2 url i key above, it give me a 404 error. I did enable apache rewrite and also set the rules at my directory. Anyone got any idea if I do wrongly in the .htaccess?

**Thanks**

Comment: Where is this .htaccess located?

Comment: The .htaccess is located at /var/www/html/manga

Comment: Is `manga` same as `myfile` shown above?